# MariaDB procedure, from a previous select create another select and return both

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures, select

I've this tables in my database, and I'm trying to select **all** the career info, including the specializations it has.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE School_Catalog (
    school_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    creation_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Career_Master(
    career_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    school_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    area_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (school_id) REFERENCES School_Catalog(school_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES Area_Catalog(area_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    INDEX(area_id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Specialization_Detail
(
    specialization_id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    career_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(127) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (career_id) REFERENCES Career_Master(career_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    INDEX(name)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

For achieving that I have this procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UThesis.getSchoolCareers(
    IN school_id_in INT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE careers CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        CM.career_id AS id,
        CM.name AS career,
        AC.name AS area
    FROM Career_Master CM
    LEFT JOIN Area_Catalog AC on AC.area_id = CM.area_id
    WHERE school_id = school_id_in;

    FOR row IN careers DO
        SELECT * from specialization_detail WHERE career_id = row.id;
    END FOR;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

But It only returns the last select, I remember once I read how to do multiple selects inside a procedure and was somthing like `Select((Select ...) AS s1, (Select ...) AS s2)` but now I've no idea, Is there any way or I should do query by query?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct syntax for *using* a cursor.  But why even use a cursor when `JOIN` will do the job much faster.  Or a `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CM.career_id AS id,
        CM.name AS career,
        AC.name AS area,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sd.name FROM specialization_detail
                         WHERE sd.career_id = row.id)
    FROM Career_Master CM
    LEFT JOIN Area_Catalog AC on AC.area_id = CM.area_id
    WHERE school_id = school_id_in
    GROUP BY 1,2;
END //
```

Comment: It's a many-to-one relationship. A career can have zero or more specializations

Comment: And in the [documentation examples](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/cursor-overview/) they use the same syntax as I `DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.c1;`

Comment: But the `FETCH` and test for completion are different.